# C - give the list of palindromes from a single line

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, palindrome

I'm trying to write a program, which looks for palindromes (between a few words in a single line) and writes them. For example:

```
    >Maszka anna rentner forfreakingsake

    >anna rentner
```

However I did manage to check the first word (until space), I have no idea how to start the checking for the next word. It should be some easy, primitive way, could anyone help me please?
What I have (not much ):

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define N 10000

    int main()
    {
    int i,j;
    char satz[N];
    char palindrome[N];

    fgets(satz);

    for(i=0; i != EOF; i++)
      satz[i] = getchar(); //first filling array with chars

    }
    printf("wth :( ");
    }
```

I want to compare satz[i] with satz[j] (j = strlen(word)-1 should be the last letter of word), palindrome[] should be array with palindromes, which I could print. But I don't know the size of array nor the length of words so I've got stuck here.

Comment: please show the code you have

Comment: You should at least tell what you tried out... and copy/paste your code here.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    char word[128];
    int i=0, ch;

    putchar('>');
    while(EOF != (ch = getchar())){
        if(isspace(ch)){
            if(i){
                int fr, bk;
                for(fr=0, bk=i-1;word[fr]==word[bk];++fr,--bk);
                if(fr < bk)//not palindromes
                    i = 0;
                else {
                    while(i)
                        putchar(word[--i]);
                    putchar(ch);
                }
            }
            if(ch == '\n')
                break;
        } else {
            word[i++] = tolower(ch);//check i < sizeof(word)
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks pretty fine and works well. But when I start this program in Windows, the console is closing immediately after giving the answer. Can I get some suggestions how to solve such problem?

Comment: @user2957781 `getchar();` or `system("pause");` write before `return 0;`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to make an array from that string. A space can be a separator in it. So just parse it and add every word to an array. Then you can use your algorithm on each element from that array.

Comment: Arrays are separated by spaces? Please explain further with an example because as is it is incorrect.

Comment: I don't think this amounts to an answer. Should probably be a comment.